# Reverse triangle inequality to the power of $p$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

In the $L_p$ space with the norm $\|f\|_p = \left(\int |f|^p\right)^{\frac 1p}$ one has the reverse triangle inequality:

$$| \|f\|_p - \|g\|_p | \le \| f - g\|_p $$

What I am interested is the same inequality, but all the norms are raised to the $p$ power:

$$\color{red}{| \|f\|_p^p - \|g\|_p^p | \le \| f - g\|_p^p }$$

It is in red because the inequality does not hold, as one can see by choosing $g = f/2$. My question is, is there a variation of this inequality such that it holds? Can you point me to related inequalities?

Comment: You mean you want a relationship between $|a^p-b^p|$ and $|a-b|^p$?

Comment: @polfosol Yes. But I think that the requirements with the norm is a weaker condition?

Comment: Side Note: Conclusion of Refined Fatou Lemma says that $\|f_n\|_{p}^{p} - \|f_n-f\|_{p}^{p} \to \|f\|_{p}^{p}$